# Convert yyyy/mm/dd-hh-mm-ss.00 to Y-m-d H:i:s in php

Tags: php, datetime

I'm developing a system that recibe a date format like: yyyy/mm/dd-hh-mm-ss.00 and I need convert it to Y-m-d H:i:s.

What I done was:

```
$newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($values[2]));
```

where $values[2] it is the date in that format, for instace: 2014/01/01-13-18-23.00. But the result is: 1970-01-01 01:00:00

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of format is that (2014/01/01-13-18-23.00)? year/month/day-hour-minute-seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `DateTime`

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d-H-i-s.00', '2014/01/01-13-18-23.00');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/104095)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [**strptime**](https://www.php.net/strptime) like

```
$format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s";
echo strptime($values[2], $format);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y/M/d-H-i-s.00", $values[2]);
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

The dateTime format for strtotime() function are predefined and you have to follow the rules to get desired result.

Mixed date time formats are available here [PHP: Compound Formats - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php)